# Fahrenheit to Celsius converter won't output the correct values? [C++]

Tags: c++

Im new to C++ so I am trying to do small projects to help me learn. When I try to run my program, the fahrenheit values print properly, but the celsius value prints as a series of numbers and letters.
Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double conversion( double& fahrenheit, double celsius)
{
    celsius = (fahrenheit - 32.0) * (5.0/9.0);
    return celsius;
}

int main()
{
    double fahrenheit;

    for ( fahrenheit = -40.0; fahrenheit <= 220.0;)
    {
        cout << fahrenheit << "F = " << conversion << "C" << endl;
        fahrenheit = fahrenheit + 10.0;
    }
    system( "pause" );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: the conversion function takes parameters

Comment: That's not how functions work.

Comment: @MooingDuck unfortunately that's not the only thing wrong with this code.

Comment: @MooingDuck Thanks! Now I feel retarded. Like I said, I'm just starting out haha. Thanks a ton for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Since nobody else wants to explain their work, here goes...

---

```
double conversion( double& fahrenheit, double celsius)
```

Okay, the problem here is your code's design is unclear. With this declaration, you're telling people that:

- It converts something, but who knows what? Remember that unlike other languages like Objective-C, the names `fahrenheit` and `celsius` don't appear at the point the function is called. **FIX:** Name it after what it does, e.g. `fahrenheit_to_celsius` or just `degF2degC`.
- It returns a `double`, apparently a celsius temperature. This is good.
- Its first parameter is a reference to a `double`. This means that you're probably going to change it. But why would it need to change `fahrenheit`, its input? **FIX:** It doesn't. Just pass it as a `double`, no reference.
- Its second parameter is a `double`, apparently a Celsius temperature. But why, though? If the caller could provide the Celsius temperature, it wouldn't need to call your function. **FIX:** You could change this to a `double&` so the function could set the Celsius temperature. *But there is no reason to do that because it's already returning that temperature as the function's return code.* **BETTER FIX:** Get rid of the parameter.

Thus the function's API should look more like:

```
double degF2degC(double fahrenheit)
```

Much simpler.

---

```
{
    celsius = (fahrenheit - 32.0) * (5.0/9.0);
    return celsius;
}
```

This part is basically fine. But we got rid of the `double celsius` (which BTW was a *copy* of the parameter passed in, and thus changes in this function won't be seen by the caller), so we need to make sure it's declared:

```
{
    double celsius = (fahrenheit - 32.0) * (5.0/9.0);
    return celsius;
}
```

But honestly, since you do nothing else with it, you should just eliminate the variable:

```
{
    return (fahrenheit - 32.0) * (5.0/9.0);
}
```

---

```
for ( fahrenheit = -40.0; fahrenheit <= 220.0;)
{
    cout << fahrenheit << "F = " << conversion << "C" << endl;
    fahrenheit = fahrenheit + 10.0;
}
```

The fundamental problem here is that `conversion` (now `degF2degC`) by itself is a *function.* It doesn't call the function; to do that you have to add `(fahrenheit)`. Without that, if this compiles, it will be because C++ will convert `conversion` to a *function pointer,* which isn't really useful to you.

That said, there are a few things that could be done better. First, the `for` statement is `for(initializer; condition; step-expression)` so the `fahrenheit = fahrenheit + 10.0;` should really be the step expression. Someone who hasn't read all the code could think this was an infinite loop.

Second, since you only use `fahrenheit` (which, BTW, is *not* the same `fahrenheit` object as in the function) in the loop, you can declare it in the initializer and remove the separate `double fahrenheit;` line.

Third, you can use the `+=` operator to avoid repeating `fahrenheit`.

Putting all this together, you get:

```
int main()
{
    for (double fahrenheit = -40.0; fahrenheit <= 220.0; fahrenheit += 10.0)
    {
        cout << fahrenheit << "F = " << degF2degC(fahrenheit) << "C" << endl;
    }
```

---

```
system( "pause" );
return 0;
```

Unless you're running this in a window that closes immediately on program completion, you don't need `system( "pause" );`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double conversion( double fahrenheit) //needs only one argument
{
    double celsius = (fahrenheit - 32.0) * (5.0/9.0);
    return celsius;
}

int main()
{
    double fahrenheit;

    for ( fahrenheit = -40.0; fahrenheit <= 220.0;fahrenheit = fahrenheit + 10.0;)
    {
        cout << fahrenheit << "F = " << conversion(fahrenheit) << "C" << endl;

    }
    system( "pause" );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: While you're fixing code, might as well move the `fahrenheit` counter to the `for` loop.  Also, it's good to note exactly what the problem was and/or what you changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
double F2C(double fair){
    double celc = (fair - 32.0) / 1.8;
    return celc;
}

double C2F(double celc){
    double fair = 1.8 * celc + 32
    return fair;
}
```

there you are

also, here is a function mock up

```
<type of value that is returned> <function name> (<parameters>){
    <function body>;
    return <value that is returned>;
}
```

and here is a function call

```
<name of function>(<function's parameters>);
```

C2F for instance, is called like this;

```
double myFahrenheitValue = C2F(22.0);
```

printing myFahrenheitValue with std::cout will output 71.6